# Hierarchical custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I need to display press statements as a custom post type ("**statement**"). Associated with each **statement** post type is one or more Authors, which is currently implemented also as a custom post type ("**sauthor**"). Each Author is supposed to have a title/post/position, e.g. Vice President of ABC, which is currently implemented as **sauthor**'s custom field ("**position**"). I use a third party plugin called "Posts to Posts" to associate **sauthor** post types with **statement** post types.

I have all of the above set up but I have a problem because the title/post/position of the Author(s) may change. Today, John Doe might be Vice President of ABC but next year, he might be Chief Janitor but I need the statements that he issued this year to still be displayed as "Vice President of ABC". Any ideas on how this could be done?

One solution that I thought of is to do away with the **sauthor** to **statement** relationship and just have the Author and his/her title as custom fields. However, I'd like the data to be related. As in each Author custom field has a Position custom field as a child to show that the data is related. But could this be done?